# how to run a single spec using ginkgo test framework

Tags: ginkgo

./I have a test suite that has 4 specs, like this:

```
var _ = Describe("Start a Cycle", func() {
  It("test 1", func() {...})
  It("test 2", func() {...})
  It("test 3", func() {...})
  It("test 4", func() {...})
})
```

I would like to run only "test 1" , the following command doesn't work, even though the documentation says it should:

```
ginkgo testDir --focus "test 1"
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

It turns out I have to put --focus before the testDir, the following command works

```
ginkgo --focus "test 1" testDir
```

Comment: For anyone using `go test` instead of `ginkgo` to run tests: `go test testDir -ginkgo.focus "test 1"`